# Lazy loading in react-router-dom v6.0.2

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

how is it possible to create lazy loading with this syntax?

```js
const A = React.lazy(() => import("./A"));
const B = React.lazy(() => import("./B"));

function App() {
return (<Routes>
    <Route
        path="firstPath"
        element={<A />} />
    
    <Route
        path="secondPath"
        element={<B />} />

</Routes>)
}
```

I was thinking that with this syntax A and B will be called when we pass them into element props and lazy loading wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can wrap all in one Suspense:

```
const Home = lazy(() => import('./home'));
const About = lazy(() => import('./about'));

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Suspense fallback={<p> Loading...</p>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, been using this approach for a while - how would this work when using an `Outlet` though? Currently our whole app shows the fallback element - even though only the screen within the outlet is changing

Answer (score 2):

It is, and you wrap the route's components in a Suspense wrapper.

[React-router Lazy Loading](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/lazy-loading)

```
import { Suspense } from 'react';

const A = React.lazy(() => import("./A"));
const B = React.lazy(() => import("./B"));

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="firstPath"
        element={
          <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
            <A />
          </Suspense>
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="secondPath"
        element={
          <Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
            <B />
          </Suspense>
        }
      />

    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm want to understand how lazy loading works in v6, there is difference between v5 to v6, in the previous version you should pass function not jsx that called createElement in first reload.

Comment: @alirezabinesh Lazy loading is a React thing, not a React-router-dom thing, it works exactly the same. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding your follow-on question? The above is the v6 route syntax.

Comment: react-router-dom help us to load component depending on the routing. but we passed called component to element props and i want to undrestand how the react-router-dom manage this? because when we call a component it is going to download and load.

Comment: @alirezabinesh I see, so your question is really something more like "How does React's lazy loading still work even though I passed a JSX literal of my component to the `Route` component?"

Comment: yes, in addition it has to load depends on the routing and it shouldn`t start loading at the first rendering

Comment: @alirezabinesh Example syntax was lifted straight from the official docs. I did a bit of digging in the source to see how `Routes` handles/controls when routes are matched and rendered, I can also link that as well and include a brief summary if that helps. Just note that simply specifying JSX doesn't mean the component is mounting and rendering, but instead, as you say, React still manages converting the JSX to Javascript functions w/ `createElement` and controls when components are mounted/etc. In other words, again, RRD has nothing to do with how React suspense works.

Comment: Does the code still get bundled and handled properly by Webpack?

Comment: @KernelJames I've not ever used lazy component loading myself in any production product, but I am inclined to say yes, it should work with any codesplitting used by webpack.

Answer (score 1):

From `v6.9.0.` react-router supports lazy loading

```
const routes = createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route path="a" lazy={() => import("./a")} />
    <Route path="b" lazy={() => import("./b")} />
  </Route>
);
```

Docs: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.9.0/route/lazy

Github: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/react-router%406.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the React Router API affords this.

Code splitting is orthogonal to module loading, i.e. it can happen correctly without having achieved the behavior of: loading modules only once routed to.

`Suspense` can be placed anywhere above, and it must be by the time we ask a question like this as the application will fault without it.

When you write `<A />` and `<B />` in this parent component's rendering, as you have, as the `Route` `element` prop values, this causes the lazy module loading to happen then, during `App` render for any route, as these expressions are renderings of `A` and `B`.

If the React-Router API permitted lazy loading, it would let you defer rendering the routed-to component until that route is selected.

The typical way any value's computation is deferred in EcmaScript is by creating a function that returns the result. For example, in some other imaginary Router API, one might be permitted to write instead `() => <A />` and `() => <B />`.

If at the basic level we end up with, internal to the imaginary Router library,  `const SelectedRoute: React.FC = () => <A />`, then the lazy load of the `A` module would commence only once render arrives at `<SelectedRoute />`.

Thank you for reading.